# How to access a classes attribute variable in other method

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-class

I am learning python3 and I want to know that how I can

```
class testit:
    def assigna():
        a = "Hi"

    def geta(self):
        print(self.a)


test = testit
print(test.geta())
```

How can I access a inside of `geta` as suggested in comments I tried to use `self.a` and it gives me an error.

Here is my Updated Code

```
class testit:
    def assigna(self):
        self.a = "Hi"

    def geta(self):
        print(self.a)


test = testit
print(test.geta())
```

and here is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 44, in <module>
    print(test.geta())
TypeError: geta() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: Did you mean: `self.a = "Hi"`?

Comment: You also would need to create an *instance* of the `testit` class and *call* its method `test.assigna()`, and add a parameter (by convention called `self`) to `assigna`.

Comment: When i try to do this it gives me an error TypeError: geta() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
now here is how my code looking loke

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @ForThis Read up on [Tutorial - 9.3.5. Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)

Answer (score 2):

when you pass `self` in argument of method it refers to an object so you have to assign `a` as object attribute before.

you also have to make an instance of this class with calling it like this `classname()`.

```
class TestIt:
    def assigna(self):
        self.a = "Hi"

    def geta(self):
        return self.a


test = TestIt()
test.assigna()
test.geta()
print(test.geta())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the instance based variable through `self` but you have to assign to it in the constructor,  Here is a little code for you:

```
class Test:
  def __init__(self):
      self.a = ""
  def assign_a(self):
      self.a = "Hi"
  def get_a(self):
     print(self.a)
```

So you can access it like :

```
test = Test()
test.assign_a()
test.get_a()
```

Here look at the `__init__` function carefully it is called the constructor and inside it we are declaring variable `a` through `self`. Now this variable will be accessible throughout the class.

Enjoy learning !!